# append array by index in nested array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I created a sample code to demo my problem, the actual data is much bigger

```js
const arr = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2,
  items: [{
    id: 1
  }]
}]

const target = 2
const nextIndex = 1
newArr = arr.map(o => o.id === target ? ({
  ...o,
  items: [...o.items, {
    id: 'new id'
  }]
}) : o);

console.log(newArr);
```

How to insert {id: 'new id'} by index? Above code is appending onto items array. Assuming I have a click event, user can insert the position of {id: 'new id} by index, I can't use append as it doesn't replace existing object.

expected output

```
[{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2,
  items: [{
    id: 1
  },{
   id: 'something'
}]
```

Above code doesn't work, adding new item to items array without using index.

Comment: Can you share the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

[The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
const target = 2;
int index = arr.findIndex(v => v.id == target);
if (index > -1) {
  arr.splice(index, 1, {id: 'new id'}); // replace 1 with 0 if you just want to insert.
}
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: **This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.** Code only answers generally are flagged as "low quality". Add below or above the code **_why_** you made the changes you did and any links to docs where it "proves" the reason you made the change are always good as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass index from onClick event

```
functionName = (i) => { //where i is index from onclick event

 arr.map( o, index) => {

  if(i === index)

  {
    const obj = {      //object
     id: 'new id'
    }
    arr[i].push(obj)   // push object at given index from onClick
  }

 }

}
```